Describe layer field names
Currently the workflow is to split two different Feature Layer by an attribute which produces a lot of separate layers. Then use arcpy.Describe to apply symbology to the based on the layer type (point/Line).
act_map = aprx.activeMap
map = aprx.listMaps("Map1")
layers = act_map.listLayers()
for lyr in layers:
    if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).dataType)=='FeatureLayer':
        if arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType=='Point':
            symbology = lyr.symbology
            symbology.updateRenderer("SimpleRenderer")
            symbol = symbology.renderer.symbol
            symbol.color = {"RGB": [169, 0, 230, 100]}
            symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 100]}               
            symbol.size = 6
            symbol.outlineWidth = 1
            lyr.symbology = symbology  # "re-set" property symboloy

This works but now we're adding another Feature Layer (Point) that will require separate Symbology. I have the idea to use "Fieldnames" to differentiate the two but can't figure it out.

Describe does quite a bit, but it's ListFields' job to list fields. Most folks use layer name to drive symbology rules.

I can't use layer name since the layers will be named based off the attribute they're split off of and will vary every project. I'll look into ListFields, Thank you.

If you're splitting the sources, you have control of the naming right there. Assuming layer contents by the most easily duplicated property  is needlessly risky (and the most difficult -- Mr. Goldberg would approve)

According to Field - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation, "Field properties can be accessed through the ListFields and Describe functions."  If you already have a Describe object for a layer, e.g., desc = arcpy.Describe(layer), retrieving the fields property will return a list of Field objects:  desc.fields.

Using arcpy.ListFields(lyr) was the solution.
act_map = aprx.activeMap
map = aprx.listMaps("Map1")
OPField = "xxxxxx"
for lyr in layers:
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(lyr)
    for field in fieldList:
        if field.name == OPField:
            symbology = lyr.symbology
            symbology.updateRenderer("SimpleRenderer")
            symbol = symbology.renderer.symbol
            symbol.color = {"RGB": [169, 0, 230, 100]}
            symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 100]}               
            symbol.size = 6
            lyr.symbology = symbology

